# How to read an escpos guide?

Tags: hex, epson, escpos

For instance, Epson's TM-T88V esc/pos manual is like

[image: escpos]

I need to supply my printer with a buffer that contains the `FS C` code to change the code page.

```
# doesnt work, the actual code page number just gets interpreted literally
\x1C \x43 0
\x1C \x430
```

How do you read escpos manuals?

Answer (score 2):

ESC/POS printer accept data as a series of bytes in your shown example to select Kanji characters for the printer. You need to send three bytes 1C 43 0  the printer will then executes the command.

However, before you send a command to an esc/pos printer you need to send a series of command first and then ends with cut command. 
For example

1. Initialize the printer with 1B 40
2. Switch to standard mode. 1B 53
3. your commands 1C 43 0
4. your data.
5. Print command. 0A
6. last command cut paper. 1D 56 00

your printer's programming manual should have detail these steps.

Comment: thanks, im doing something wrong programatically on my end